# How to force Python RegEx to match all possible groups connected by | (*OR*)

Tags: python, regex

I am new to RegEx, and I wonder if there is a way that we can force RegEx to match all possible groups (if there are multiple) at the same 'match' where patterns are connected by *OR* (see below).

I've tried this: `(?P<broad>travel)|(?P<step>step)|(?P<dist>distance|far|km)`, but if the input is: `Tell me how many steps I traveled`, the code only matches one of travel or step. I've also tried using `findall` instead of `search`, but then the group information is lost (because the output is a list).

I expect that the code can match all possible groups in the same 'match' if available, instead of quitting as soon as a match is found.

Current output:

```
Match 1
broad   None
step    step
dist    None
Match 2
broad   travel
step    None
dist    None
```

Expected output:

```
Match 1
broad   travel
step    step
dist    None
```

Comment: @Emma, as you can see in your provided link, the two words are not captured in the same 'match', but how can I make them in the same 'match'?

Comment: @Emma, please see the post for my clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe here, we can use `finditer` and test our expression:

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uHU8M9/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(travel)|(step)|(distance|far|km)"

test_str = "Tell me how many steps I traveled"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /(travel)|(step)|(distance|far|km)/gm;
const str = `Tell me how many steps I traveled`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```